# Django User Class (django.contrib.auth) fname not working

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

In my website, I can't display the user.fname. Everything else in user, like user.username, user.email, and user.password work, but i cant display the name.

PS: ive tried user.fname, user.name, user.name, user.first_name so far, none display anything

EDIT:

```
user = request.user
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    fname = request.user.get_short_name()
return render(request, 'student/dashboard.html', {'user': user, 'fname': fname})
```

I added this, but i still cant call it for some reason (this is my views)

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
        GRADE_CHOICES = ( 
                    (9,'9'), (10,'10'), (11,'11'), (12,'12') , 
                )
        curr_year = date.today().year
        GRAD_YEAR_CHOICES = ( 
                    (curr_year,curr_year), (curr_year+1,curr_year+1), (curr_year+2,curr_year+2), (curr_year+3,curr_year+3) , 
                     )
        fname = forms.CharField(max_length = 25)
        lname = forms.CharField( max_length = 25)
        emailid = forms.EmailField()
        passwd1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.PasswordInput)
        passwd2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.PasswordInput)
        gradyear = forms.ChoiceField( choices=GRAD_YEAR_CHOICES)
        grade = forms.ChoiceField( choices=GRADE_CHOICES)
```

This is in my forms.py

Comment: Do you get any error? Did you check the database? Did you place a debug breakpoint and saw what request.user object holds? There are chances that your if condition is failing. Because for an anonymous user, these things are empty

Comment: when i changed fname to a string, it displayed. So therefore, i addume that the user.fname is empty, for some reason @VishalSh

Comment: Add a breakpoint at your if statetement and look into request.user object. Also check `auth_user` table and go throught the entries over there. Also, use `request.user.first_name`

Comment: what do you mean "look into"?? @VishalSh

Comment: Are you using any ide?

Comment: No, just running the server from command line and seeing if it displays on the localhost @VishalSh

Comment: Okay.. write a print statement before your if condition. print(request.user.username) and see what you get

Comment: I used a DB editor, and saw that first and last name were getting no info, found my problem, thanks for all the help @VishalSh

Comment: Yep, the first comment was enough to understand. Use SQLworkbench. Makes life easy

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 user.first_name
 user.last_name
```

if the user is already loggedin you can use in your views:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    username = request.user.get_username()
```

more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: nope, this didnt work. Im starting to think theres a problem with my code somewhere?